# Akka context become recursive function

Tags: akka, state

I have an actor in which I mutate the state using context.become: Here is the snippet:

```
def stateMachine(state: State): Receive = {
  case a => {
    ... do something
    context.become(stateMachine(newState))
  }

  case b => {
    ... do something
    sender ! state
  }

  case c => {
    ... do something
    context.become(stateMachine(newState))
  }
}
```

My IntelliJ says that my stateMachine(...) function is recursive. Is this a problem? Should I be concerned? Is there something fundamentally wrong with my approach in the above example?

Comment: it probably is a problem. since from your code it seems you just want to mutate the context, but actually you are making a recursive call until `case b` is reached. could you show where `newState` is from?

Comment: and it seems your state machine doesn't call `unbecome`, it doesn't sound good.

Comment: newState is the result of doing something on the respective case blocks! The resursive warning goes of if I do a self ! newState but that would be wrong? or?

Comment: When should I call unbecome and why would I ned to do this? I want my state to evolve only inside this stateMachine and this should happen until this Actor dies.

Comment: ok. so i see the problem. if your state machine is just a process of handling you business, then it's perfectly fine to be recursive. however, in the middle of such business you make the context `become` something else. what i guess you would do is just call such state machine without `become` in `receive`, and it's probably what you really want. let me know, if that's true, i will post an answer.

Comment: I have a prestart on this actor which initializes the state, does a self ! state and in the receive method, I do a context.become(stateMachine(state)). After this point every state evolution happens in the stateMachine method!

Comment: the problem here is your context keeps being stacked up until `case b` is reached. and `become` and `unbecome` is a pair relationship that's actually a stack. so your `become` code will gradually eat up all your memory. probably you need to provide some critical fraction in `receive` for further suggestion.

Comment: Could you please post a solution?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The approach you are using is fine, it is a common way to implement state inside an Actor without using var. The default version of `context.become` does not maintain a stack, it just replaces the existing functionality with the new one. The is called "HotSwap". To maintain a stack, you would have to add `discardOld = false`.

http://doc.akka.io/docs/akka/snapshot/scala/actors.html#become-unbecome

http://doc.akka.io/docs/akka/1.3.1/scala/actors.html#actor-hotswap

Comment: But why the stateMachine function in my example above is a recursive function? All I do is to set the receive method using context.become. So why would that be a recursive function?

Comment: Intellij is trying to recognise instances of recursion, but it is not perfect. Because you call `stateMachine` from within `stateMachine` it looks like recursion.